# How to increase default buffersize in AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: netty, asynchttpclient, ning

How to increase default buffer size in AsyncHttpClient. 
I am using following code to read messages from a streaming server(Http long pooling).

When server sends a message longer than 8KB, then my message is divided in to chunks.

Ex:-

**Original message** :-

This is my Test Message

**Received message** :-

This is my

Test

Message

Is there any way to increase buffer size? So that i receive entire message in one part?

My Code

```
AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder config = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
    .setConnectionTimeoutInMs(120000)
    .setRequestTimeoutInMs(-1)
    .setIdleConnectionTimeoutInMs(120000)
    .setMaxConnectionLifeTimeInMs(-1);          
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(config.build());   
    Future<String> f = client.prepareGet("http://IP:PORT/context/test").execute(
            new AsyncHandler<String>() {
                private ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                @Override
                public STATE onBodyPartReceived(
                        HttpResponseBodyPart bodyPart) throws Exception {
                     String data = new String(bodyPart.getBodyPartBytes());
                     System.out.println("My Message : ---------------------------- >" + data);                  
                    return STATE.CONTINUE;
                }

            });
    f.get();
}
```

I tried to accumulate message body parts, but that require separate logic in server size to know end of message.

Thanks,

Ravi

Comment: You should change it on the server side. It's not client issue.

Comment: I have a web socket client which is able to receive messages more than 8KB. But this client is not able to receive messages more than 8KB. asynchttpclient does not allow to set max message size ...

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of buffer size in AsyncHttpClient, that's how your response is split into TCP frames over the wire. If you don't want to have control over each chunk but are ready to have them buffered in memory and only be handled the full body, use a `AsyncCompletionHandler` instead of the low level `AsyncHandler`.